# passing HTML to template in Meteor

Tags: regex, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm making my first Meteor app - a regular expression matcher is the first component that I'm making. It will highlight matching items in an editable string by surrounding the matches with a span tag.

I figured out how to create the tags around matches in vanilla JavaScript:
http://jsbin.com/iXUVUJA/1/

But the way I added it into a Meteor template, the tags are being shown in the browser. Is there a way to have the tags read as html in the browser?

Here is the relevant code from my .js file:

```js
var str = "There are thousands and thousands of uses for corn... All of which I will tell you about right now.";
var regEx = /[A-Z]/g;

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.sampleText.someText = function() {
    return str.replace(regEx, ("span class='highlighted'>" + "$&" + "</span>") );
  };
}
```

And here is the relevant code from my .html file:

```
<template name="sampleText">
  {{someText}}
</template>
```

This is the output on the page from the server:

span class='highlighted'>There are thousands and thousands of uses for corn... span class='highlighted'>All of which span class='highlighted'>I will tell you about right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Handlebars.SafeString`, as seen in the Handlebars [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/). In your case you can do:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.sampleText.someText = function() {
    var element = str.replace(regEx, ("span class='highlighted'>" + "$&" + "</span>") );
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(element);
  };
}
```